# MySql Entity Framework Code-Firsrt

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

Estoy tratando de persistir contra una base de datos MySql usando Entity Framework la aproximación Code-First, uso en EF6
No me da error, **el problema es que no me crea la base de datos ni la tabla ni agrega los registros que persisto.**

muestro código de implementación.

App.config

```
<configuration>


<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DemoContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=demozmarket;uid=root;password=123456" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="DemoMySqlEntityFramework.MySqlEFConfiguration, DemoMySqlEntityFramework">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" >
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" 
           invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Maps(Fluent Api)

```
namespace DemoMySqlEntityFramework.Data.Modelo.Maps
{
    public class ClienteMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
    {
        public ClienteMap()
        {
            ToTable("Clientes");
            HasKey(c => c.ClienteId);
            Property(c => c.ClienteId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnOrder(0);
            Property(c => c.RazonSocial).IsRequired().HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnOrder(1);
            Property(c => c.Direccion).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnOrder(2);
            Property(c => c.Fecha).HasColumnOrder(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Clase DbContext

```
namespace DemoMySqlEntityFramework.Data.Modelo
{

    public class DemoContext : DbContext
    {
        public DemoContext() : base("DemoZMarket")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClienteMap());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            //modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            //modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

Entidades

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

Repository

```
public class ClienteReposotory
{
    public void Create(Cliente entity)
    {
        using (var context = new DemoContext())
        {
            context.Clientes.Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Le envio datos

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly ClienteReposotory _clienteReposotory = new ClienteReposotory();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cliente = new Cliente()
        {
            RazonSocial = "COMERCIAL PEPITO",
            Direccion = "MI CASA",
            Fecha = new DateTime(1976, 08, 10)
        };

        _clienteReposotory.Create(cliente);

    }
}
```

Me da este error cuando pongo en la consola Enable-Migrations o cualquier otro comando de migrations.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName  "DemoContext" -

EnableAutomaticMigrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
   en MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   en System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   en System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   en System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   en System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   en System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   en System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   en System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action 

command)

**`Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.`**
```

Comment: Donde exactamente te da el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione había tomado el nombre de mi clase MyContex en el name de la conexión cuando debí poner demozmarket

```
public DemoContext() : base("demozmarket")
```

ConectionString

```
<add name="demozmarket" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=demozmarket;Uid=root;Pwd=xxxx" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**"El problema es que no me crea la base de datos ni la tabla ni agrega los registros que persisto".**

Verifica varias cosas:

1. ¿Habilitaste las migraciones automáticas?

Para habilitar las migraciones automáticas tenemos que ejecutar el comando

```
Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

En la consola de NuGet (recordando que como proyecto predeterminado en la consola tenemos que seleccionar el que contenga nuestra clase de contexto).

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName  "NombreclaseDelContexto" -EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

2. Si habilitaste las migraciones automáticas.¿ Le diste el comando Update-Database en la consola de NuGet.

Cuando se ejecuta el comando

```
Update-Database
```

Se obliga a realizar la creacion de la Bd y si ya existe y no importa la eliminación o destrucción de la estructura de la tabla y sus datos debe agregar el  Update-Database -force

Sugiero mirar estos comandos y si se presenta un mensaje de error lo publique.

Comment: Hola si he probado lo que me comentas Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations, Enable-Migrations me dale el siguiente error: Se produjo una excepción en el inicializador de tipo de 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1'. no he podido encontrar una solución para eso.

Comment: @PedroÁvila. Creo que el problema esta en la conexión a la base de datos, en el <connectionStrings>. Veo que en el contexto DemoContext, el constructor llama a "DemoZMarket" mientras que su <connectionStrings> en el WebConfig lo tiene definido como "DemoContext"

Comment: @PedroÁvila. Te sugiero que mires esta pagina. A mi me parece muy fácil de entender y si es necesario podrías repasar todo el proceso: http://panicoenlaxbox.blogspot.com.co/2013/05/rompiendo-el-hielo-con-code-first.html

Comment: Ya lo solucione, gracias.